# Closed-form expression for $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}kk^p$ for integers $n,\,p$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

Is there a closed-form expression for the sum $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}kk^p$ given positive integers $n,\,p$? Earlier I thought of this series but failed to figure out a closed-form expression in $n,\,p$ (other than the trivial case $p=0$).

$$p=0\colon\,\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}kk^0=2^n$$

I know that $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k=2^n$ and $\sum_{k=0}^nk^n=\frac{k^{n+1}-1}{k-1}$ but I am unsure of whether these would be of much use now.

---

Additionally, what about the similar series $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}kk^n$ where $p=n$?

Comment: Is it $k^p$ or $k^n$?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal $k^p$, my mistake -- though that series looks very interesting as well! :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you consider $p$ as fixed, then the below can be considered as closed form I suppose:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} k^p = \sum_{k=1}^{p} S(p,k) n(n-1)\dots(n-k+1) 2^{n-k} \quad \quad (1)$$

where $S(k,p)$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

If you denote the operator of differentiating and multiplying by $x$ as $D_{x}$

Then we have that

$$(D_{x})^{n}f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} S(n,k) f^{k}(x) x^{k}$$

where $S(n,k)$ is the Stirling number of the second kind and $f^k(x)$ is the $k^{th}$ derivative of $f(x)$.

This can easily be proven using the identity $$S(n,k) = S(n-1,k-1) + k \cdot S(n-1,k)$$

To prove $(1)$ above, we apply $D_x$, $p$ times to $(1+x)^n$, and set $x=1$.

Comment: Interesting approach. Am I right in concluding this is roughly the same argument as in Michael's solution above?

Comment: @oldrinb: Yes, but it aims to give a formula in terms of well known numbers :-). The approach of differentiating and multiplying by $x$ is a pretty well known approach. For instance, see my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4317/generalizing-sum-limits-n-1-infty-n2-xn-to-sum-limits-n-1/4344#4344

Comment: thanks for that... I haven't been exposed to this before!

Comment: In your formula, is it $s(p,k)$ or s(k,p)?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: $s(p,k)$, same as what you have.

Comment: It should be $2^n$ not $2^{n-k}$, because you are multiplying by $x^k$ after applying $D^k$.

Comment: @Aryabhata: You should correct your formula in $(1)$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: No, $D_x$ is the operator of "differentiate _and_ multiply by $x$". There is no multiply by $x^k$ after $D^k$.

Comment: @Aryabhata: here is the formula you use $(D_{x})^{n}f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} s(n,k) f^{k}(x) x^{k}$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: Yes, by setting $x=1$, $x^k$ disappears. The $2^{n-k}$ comes from $f^k(x)$, where $f(x) = (1+x)^n$. I don't see your point.

Comment: @Aryabhata: Ok I see your point.

Comment: In your formula $(1)$, it should be $s(p,k)$ not $s(k,p)$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: Right, thanks for pointing that out. Corrected.

Comment: @Aryabhata: No problem (+1).

Answer (score 10):

Let 
$$
f(x)=(e^x+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}e^{kx}.
$$

Then 
$$
\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^p f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}k^pe^{kx}.$$

Plug in $x=0$.

Comment: Elegant and concise -- too good! Pretty neat.

Comment: @oldrinb: I guess our definitions of closed form formula differ :-) Or do you see an easy way to compute the left side in this answer?

Comment: @Aryabhata true, I was just surprised by how concise this was.

Comment: Of course, we could write it as an integral (Cauchy's formula), so +1 to this answer.

Comment: @Aryabhata: The closed form that you have will follow from this, use $e^x+1=e^x-1+2$. (+1) on your answer!

Comment: @i707107: Yes, but then it won't be as concise :-). If you write it as an integral, it will be!

Comment: Note that $(e^x-1)^k/k!=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s(n,k)x^n/n!$.

Comment: Aha! @i707107 I now understand your comments. That is the exponential generating function of the Stirling numbers of the second kind, and expanding by the binomial theorem gives us Aryabhata's result.

Answer (score 8):

We know that $(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k$.Differentiate this, to get $n(1+x)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} k x^{k-1}$. Multiply by $x$ to get $nx(1+x)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} k x^k$. Take $x=1$ to get the first sum, And repeat this process for sums involving higher powers of $k$.

Comment: Brilliant! I would have never seen this.

Answer (score 8):

Use the identity $k\dbinom{n}k=n\dbinom{n-1}{k-1}$: for $p=1$ you get

$$\sum_k\binom{n}kk=n\sum_k\binom{n-1}{k-1}=n\sum_k\binom{n-1}k=n2^{n-1}\;.$$

For $p=2$:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_k\binom{n}kk^2&=n\sum_k\binom{n-1}{k-1}k\\
&=n\sum_k\binom{n-1}k(k+1)\\
&=n\sum_k\binom{n-1}kk+n\sum_k\binom{n-1}k\\
&=n(n-1)\sum_k\binom{n-2}{k-1}+n2^{n-1}\\
&=n(n-1)\sum_k\binom{n-2}k+n2^{n-1}\\
&=n(n-1)2^{n-2}+n2^{n-1}\;.
\end{align*}$$

If you carry out the same sort of computation with $p=3$, you get

$$\sum_k\binom{n}kk^3=n(n-1)(n-2)2^{n-3}+2n(n-1)2^{n-2}+n2^{n-1}\;,$$

which can be written with [falling factorials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol) as $$\sum_k\binom{n}kk^3=n^{\underline3}2^{n-3}+3n^{\underline2}2^{n-2}+n^{\underline1}2^{n-1}\;.$$

After a little more experimentation one may conjecture and prove by induction that

$$\sum_k\binom{n}kk^p=\sum_{k=1}^p{p\brace k}n^{\underline k}2^{n-k}\;,$$

where $p\brace k$ is the [Stirling number of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: This does make sense and it's an interesting approach. Thank you!

Comment: @oldrinb: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 3):

A [relate problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225908/why-m-power-by-n-equals-sum-of-n-numbrs). Try this formula
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}kk^p= 2^n\sum_{k=0}^{p}\begin{Bmatrix} p\\k \end{Bmatrix} {n\choose k}2^{-k}k!, $$

where $p \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\begin{Bmatrix} p\\k \end{Bmatrix}$ is the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). You can plug in $p=n$ in the above formula.

Comment: You might be missing a $2^{-k}$ factor inside the $\sum$.

Comment: @Aryabhata: Thanks for the comment. It should be ok.

Comment: I don't understand. As the answer currently stands, I believe you have it wrong (at least two other answers differ from this) and was pointing that out, before someone comes around and downvotes :-)

Comment: By the way, this answer was posted before other answers.

Comment: You can clearly see the times the other answers were posted, Mhenni. For instance, Brian's answer was 14 mins before yours. Perhaps you didn't refresh your page.

Comment: @Aryabhata: Thanks for the correction.

Comment: but +1 though, as this answer now seems correct.

Comment: @Aryabhata: Do not worry. I do not mean any body, but I am driving the attention of the reader that this answer stands for its own.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} k^p.$$

Introduce
$$k^p = \frac{p!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{p+1}} \exp(kz) \; dz.$$

This yields for the sum
$$\frac{p!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{p+1}} 
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} \exp(kz) \; dz
\\ = \frac{p!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{p+1}} 
(1+\exp(z))^n \; dz
\\ = \frac{p!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{p+1}} 
(2+\exp(z)-1)^n \; dz
\\ = \frac{p!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{p+1}} 
\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (\exp(z)-1)^q 2^{n-q} \; dz
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} \times q! \times  2^{n-q} \times
\frac{p!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{p+1}} 
\frac{(\exp(z)-1)^q}{q!} \; dz.$$

Recall the species equation for labelled set partitions:
$$\mathfrak{P}(\mathcal{U}\mathfrak{P}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z}))$$

which yields the bivariate generating function of the Stirling numbers
of the second kind
$$\exp(u(\exp(z)-1)).$$

Substitute this into the sum to get
$$\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} \times q! \times  2^{n-q}
\times {p\brace q}$$

Now observe  that when $n\gt  p$ the Stirling  number is zero  for the
values $p\lt q \le n$ so we  may replace $n$ by $p.$ On the other hand
when $n\lt p$ the binomial coefficient  is zero for the values $n\lt q
\le p$ so we may again replace $n$ by $p.$ This finally yields

$$\sum_{q=0}^p {n\choose q} \times q! \times  2^{n-q}
\times {p\brace q}$$

as observed by the other contributors.

Answer (score 0):

We have:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} k^p =
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} \left[\sum_{j=0}^p j! {k\choose j} {p\brace j}\right] =
\sum_{j=0}^p j! \left[\sum_{k=j}^n {n\choose k} {k\choose j} \right] {p\brace j} =
\sum_{j=0}^p j! 2^{n-j}{n\choose j} {p\brace j} ,$$

with $p\brace j$ being the Stirling number of the second kind.