# Show that it is the solution of the recurrence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, recurrence-relations

I have to show that the solution of the recurrence $$X(1)=1, X(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}X(i)X(n-i), \text{ for } n>1$$
is $$X(n+1)=\frac{1}{n+1} \binom{2n}{n}$$

I used induction to show that.

I have done the following:

For $n=0$ : $X(1)=1 \checkmark $

We assume that it stands for each $1 \leq k \leq n$:
$$X(k)=\frac{1}{k}\binom{2(k-1)}{k-1} \ \ \ \ \ (*)$$

We want to show that it stands for $n+1$:

$$X(n+1)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} X(i)X(n+1-i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i}\binom{2(i-1)}{i-1}\frac{1}{n+1-i}\binom{2(n-i)}{n-i}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}\frac{(2(i-1))!}{(i-1)!(2(i-1)-(i-1))!}\frac{1}{n+1-i}\binom{(2(n-i))!}{(n-1)!(2(n-i)-(n-i))!}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(2(i-1))!}{i!(i-1)!}\frac{(2(n-i))!}{(n-i+1)!(n-i)!}$$

How could I continue??

Comment: @Lucian Can you be more explicit? The top term is not constant, so how do we apply this here?

Comment: @SuzuHirose Do you maybe have an idea what I could do??

Comment: I looked at this but didn't get anywhere. There are quite a few formulas for (2n n) but I couldn't get any to work.

Comment: What I noticed from Marko Riedel's answer, reading [the Wikipedia article about the Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) there seems to be no easy combinatoric argument for this formula.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Could we maybe use the formula $$\binom{2n}{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}^2$$ ??

Comment: Maybe, but I couldn't see how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

These are the Catalan numbers.

This can be done by generating functions which is quite simple.
Set $X_0=0$ and $X_1=1$ and introduce 
$$f(w) = \sum_{n\ge 0} X_n w^n.$$

Because $X_0=0$ we can extend the recurrence to
$$X_n = \sum_{q=0}^n X_q X_{n-q}$$
for $n>1.$

This says that, again for $n>1,$
$$[w^n] f(w) = [w^n] f(w)^2.$$

Multiply by $w^n$ and sum over $n>1$ to get
$$\sum_{n\gt 1} w^n [w^n] f(w) =
\sum_{n\gt 1} w^n [w^n] f(w)^2.$$

This is an *annihilated coefficient extractor* (ACE) 
and it simplifies to
$$f(w) - X_1 w - X_0 = f(w)^2 - 2X_0 X_1 w - X_0$$
which is
$$f(w) - w = f(w)^2.$$

Solve the quadratic and pick the proper solution to finally obtain
$$f(w) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{1-4w}}{2}.$$

We can  extract coefficients  from this in  various ways, by table
lookup or using Lagrange inversion. The Newton binomial series gives
$$[w^n] \sqrt{1-w} =
(-1)^n {1/2 \choose n}
\\ = (-1)^n 
\frac{1/2 \times (-1/2) \times (-3/2) \times \cdots
\times  }{n!}
= (-1)^n \frac{1}{2^n n!} \times (-1)^{n-1}
\prod_{k=0}^{n-2} (2k+1)
\\ = - \frac{1}{2^n n!} \frac{(2n-3)!}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-2} (2k)} 
= - \frac{1}{2^n n!} \frac{(2n-3)!}{2^{n-2} (n-2)!} 
= - \frac{1}{2^{2n-1} (n-1)} {2n-2\choose n-2}.$$

The conclusion is that
$$[w^n] f(w) = \frac{1}{2^{2n} (n-1)} 4^n {2n-2\choose n-2}
= \frac{1}{n-1} {2n-2\choose n-2}.$$

Re-write this as
$$\frac{1}{n-1} \frac{n-1}{n} {2n-2\choose n-1}
= \frac{1}{n} {2n-2\choose n-1}$$
which also holds for $n=1.$

The ACE technique is also used at this 
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371011).

Comment: We cannot show this using induction, right?? Is there also an other way to prove this besides using the ACE technique?? Maybe using the formula $$\binom{2n}{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}^2$$ or something else??

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{{\rm X}\pars{1} = 1\,,\qquad\mbox{and}\qquad
     {\rm X}\pars{n} =
     \sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n - 1}{\rm X}\pars{i}{\rm X}\pars{n - i}\,,
     \quad\mbox{for}\quad n\ >\ 1}$.

> Lets $\ds{{\cal X}\pars{z} \equiv \sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{\rm X}\pars{n}z^{n}}$,
>   with $\ds{\verts{z} < {1 \over 4}}$, such that
>   \begin{align}
> {\cal X}\pars{z}&={\rm X}\pars{1}z + \sum_{n\ =\ 2}^{\infty}{\rm X}\pars{n}z^{n}
> =z + \sum_{n\ =\ 2}^{\infty}\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n - 1}
> {\rm X}\pars{i}{\rm X}\pars{n - i}z^{n}
> \\[5mm]&=z + \sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{\rm X}\pars{i}
> \sum_{n\ =\ 1 + i}^{\infty}{\rm X}\pars{n - i}z^{n}
> =z + \sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{\rm X}\pars{i}
> \sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{\rm X}\pars{n}z^{n + i}
> \\[5mm]&=z + \bracks{\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{\rm X}\pars{i}z^{i}}
> \bracks{\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{\rm X}\pars{n}z^{n}}=z + {\cal X}^{2}\pars{z}
> \end{align}

Then, $\ds{{\cal X}^{2}\pars{z} - {\cal X}\pars{z} + z = 0}$. This
$\ds{{\cal X}\pars{z}}$-equation has two solutions:
$\ds{1 \pm \root{1 - 4z} \over 2}$.
Since $\ds{\lim_{z\ \to\ 0}{\cal X}\pars{z} = 0}$, the $\ds{{\cal X}\pars{z}}$
correct solution is given by:
\begin{align}
{\cal X}\pars{z}&={1 - \root{1 - 4z} \over 2}
=\half\bracks{1 - \sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1/2 \choose n}\pars{-4z}^{n}}
=-\,\half\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1/2 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}4^{n}z^{n}
\end{align}

> which leads to
>   \begin{align}{\rm X}\pars{n}&=-\,\half{1/2 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}4^{n}
> =\pars{-1}^{n + 1}{1/2 \choose n}2^{2n - 1}
> =\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\,{\Gamma\pars{3/2} \over n!\,\Gamma\pars{3/2 - n}}\,2^{2n - 1}
> \\[5mm]&=\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\root{\pi}\,{1 \over n!}\,
> {1 \over \Gamma\pars{3/2 - n}}\,2^{2n - 2}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\pars{1}
> \end{align}

However, by using [well known Gamma Function identities](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_255.htm):

\begin{align}
\Gamma\pars{{3 \over 2} - n}&
={\pi \over \Gamma\pars{n - 1/2}\sin\pars{\pi\bracks{n - 1/2}}}
={\pi\over \bracks{\Gamma\pars{n + 1/2}/\pars{n - 1/2}}\bracks{-\cos\pars{n\pi}}}
\\[5mm]&={\pi\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\pars{n - 1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{n + 1/2}}
=\pi\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\pars{n - 1/2}\,
{\pars{2\pi}^{-1/2}2^{2n - 1/2}\Gamma\pars{n} \over \Gamma\pars{2n}}
\\[5mm]&=\root{\pi}\pars{-1}^{n + 1}2^{2n - 2}\pars{2n - 1}
\,{\pars{n - 1}! \over \pars{2n - 1}!}
=\root{\pi}\pars{-1}^{n + 1}2^{2n - 2}
\,{\pars{n - 1}! \over \pars{2n - 2}!}
\\[5mm]&=\root{\pi}\pars{-1}^{n + 1}2^{2n - 2}\,{1 \over \pars{n - 1}!}\,
{1 \over {2n - 2 \choose n - 1}}
\end{align}

> which we'll replace in expression $\pars{1}$:
>   $$\color{#66f}{\large{\rm X}\pars{n}}
> =\color{#66f}{\large{1 \over n}\,{2n - 2 \choose n - 1}}
> \quad\imp\quad
> \color{#66f}{\large{\rm X}\pars{n + 1}}
> =\color{#66f}{\large{1 \over n + 1}\,{2n \choose n}}
> $$

Comment: (+1). Nice work. The two answers are very similar. Good to see it confirmed.

Comment: We cannot show this using induction, right?? Is there also an other way to prove this besides using the Gamma function?? Maybe using the formula $$\binom{2n}{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}^2$$ or something else??