# The binomial formula. how to show: $\Sigma_{k=0}^n k \binom{n}{k} = n2^{n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics

Does anyone know how to show that: $\Sigma_{k=0}^n k \binom{n}{k} = n2^{n-1}$?

I think we are suppose to use the binomial formula for that..

Thank you!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355262/closed-form-expression-for-sum-k-0n-binomnkkp-for-integers-n-p is a generalization of your question.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to take the derivative at $x=1$ of the binomial identity
$$
(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Differentiate both sides of: $(x+1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \cdot x^k$ and put $x = 1$ to get the answer.